# QGraphicsObject auto destruction

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qobject

`QGraphicsObject` inherit from both `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject`, but unlike most of QObject subclasses the constructor of QGraphicsObject doesn't have a `QObject *parent` parameter.

so does that mean that I should provide such a parameter in the constructor when I subclass it or even use `setParent` method to have the auto-destruction feature ?

PS: I have Qt 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't. `QGraphicsItem` has its own parent/children hierarchy. The life time of QGraphicsItems is managed like QObjects. The parent item is responsible of destroying its children. And if a QGraphicsItem is owned by a `QGraphicsScene`, the scene is managing its life time.